# C# - XElement from XSD or XML

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xelement

I have to dialogue with a webservice whose response accepts a XElement object that represents a XML file. I have generated a XSD file from the XML and, via xsd.exe, I have generated a .cs class. What I want to know is: how I can convert the object from the .cs file into Xelement in order to provide it to the request? Is there a way to convert the XML to a XML object without declaring the nodes manually?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example If you have a `class.cs` You should use [Serialization](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813)

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      clsPerson p=new clsPerson();
      p.FirstName = "Jeff";
      p.MI = "A";
      p.LastName = "Price";
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
      x.Serialize(Console.Out, p);
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
```

Comment: In which line do you convert the p object into a XElement object?

Comment: You can loop on list and convert to list

Comment: Suppose there is another filed "Address". If I do not specify p.Address the serialized XML does not show the entire tag <Address>. Is there a way to show the Address tag blank if not specified?